# Will the dbcontext dispose and close if using adddbcontext this way?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("dbconnection"));
}
```

### TestController.cs

```
private readonly TestContext _db;
public TestController(TestContext db)
{
     _db = db;
}
public void Get()
{
    DALUser dal = new DALUser(_db);
    var list = dal.Get();
}
```

### DALUser.cs

```
private readonly TestContext _db;
public DALUser(TestContext db)
{
     _db = db;
}
public IQueryable<User> Get()
{
    _db.Users.AsQueryable();
}
```

Will the dbcontext dispose and close after executing Get() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default lifetime for DatabaseContext is scoped . So in your web application , DatabaseContext disposed after your http request finished ( TestController-Get ) .

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext<TContext>(
        [NotNull] this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        [CanBeNull] Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = null,
        ServiceLifetime contextLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped,
        ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
        where TContext : DbContext
```